# How does the call pass its argument to the inner function?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

The argument 10 gets passed to the anonymous inner function, bypassing the outer function. What is the principle here?

```
function aFunc() {
  let firstNum = 2;
  return (secondNum) => secondNum * firstNum;
}
let aVar = aFunc();
console.log(aVar(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `aVar` is `(secondNum) => secondNum * firstNum` where `firstNum` and the closure has `firstNum = 2`.

```
function aFunc() {
  let firstNum = 2;
  return (secondNum) => secondNum * firstNum;
}
let aVar = aFunc();
```

Calling `aFunc()` runs the function which creates a closure around `firstNum` and returning the arrow function `(secondNum) => secondNum * firstNum`.

The subsequent call to `aVar(10)` calls this arrow function and the result of adding `firstNum` (2) and `secondNum` (10) is calculated and returned.

```
console.log(aVar(10));
```

Comment: This is not a dupe because...?